# Unable to connect to the remote server error when using kubectl and minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, kubectl, minikube

I have installed the following:

docker version 19.03.8, minikube version 1.8.2, kubectl version 1.15.5.

And created a deployment YAML file that looks like this:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hellowworldservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 8081
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 8080
      # Port accessible outside cluster
      nodePort: 30005
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: tutum/hello-world
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

The pods and deployments start successfully:

```
PS C:\kubernetes> kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
service/hellowworldservice created
deployment.apps/hello-world created
PS C:\kubernetes> kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-world-889b5c84c-98vvx   1/1     Running   0          25s
hello-world-889b5c84c-bs48d   1/1     Running   0          25s
hello-world-889b5c84c-hm6j2   1/1     Running   0          25s
hello-world-889b5c84c-hzqcc   1/1     Running   0          25s
hello-world-889b5c84c-xg5nl   1/1     Running   0          25s
PS C:\kubernetes> kubectl get deployments
NAME          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-world   5/5     5            5           40s
```

I can access the IP Address by pinging it, but not via the port where the "Hello World" webpage is supposed to be.  Why is this?

```
PS C:\kubernetes> minikube ip
172.17.45.76
PS C:\kubernetes> ping 172.17.45.76

Pinging 172.17.45.76 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.17.45.76: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.17.45.76: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.17.45.76: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.17.45.76: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 172.17.45.76:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
PS C:\kubernetes> curl http://172.17.45.76:30005
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://172.17.45.76:30005
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you are using wrong `targetPort: 8080` instead of correct `targetPort: 80`.

Reason for that - [tutum/hello-world](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/hello-world/)

> Has Apache with a 'Hello World' page listening in port 80.

You can check it from any pod.

```
 $ kubectl get pod -l app=hello-world -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo == Pod %; kubectl exec -ti % -- netstat -tunaple'
== Pod hello-world-5df464dd44-fcz9g
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro


#check all pods
$ kubectl get pods -l app=hello-world | grep hello-world |grep Running | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo == Pod %; kubectl exec -ti % -- netstat -nat'
```

Correct yaml(I also commented last line):

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hellowworldservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      # Port accessible inside cluster
      port: 8081
      # Port to forward to inside the pod
      targetPort: 80
      # Port accessible outside cluster
      nodePort: 30005
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world
          image: tutum/hello-world
          ports:
#         - containerPort: 80
```

Result:

```
$ minikube service hellowworldservice --url
http://172.17.0.2:30005
$ curl $(minikube service hellowworldservice --url)
...
    <title>Hello world!</title>
...
<body>
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" />
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <h3>My hostname is hello-world-5df464dd44-tqzbz</h3>    
...
```